# Как завершить выполнение рекурсивной функции в JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поле с количеством баллов, и 3 кнопки.

При нажатии на каждую кнопку вычитается определенное количество баллов из общего числа. Одновременно с этим, при нажатии на любую из кнопок, запускаются таймеры, отсчет которых ведется в самих кнопках. Когда таймер доходит до нуля, кнопка снова приобретает изначальный вид. При повторном нажатии на кнопку, таймеры  должны начинать отсчет по новой.

В данный момент, при повторном нажатии функции запускаются повторно, из-за чего таймер начинает идти быстрее. Спасибо за помощь заранее.

```js
//Нажатие на кнопки и изменение кол-ва баллов
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new').click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(+$('#counter').html() - 5);
  });

  $('#save').click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(+$('#counter').html() - 2);
  });

  $('#deact').click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(+$('#counter').html() - 1);
  });

});

function start_timers() {
  /* timer_new('click');
   * это должен быть выход их рекурсии, н оон не робит((
   */
  timer_new();
  timer_save();
  timer_deact();
}

function timer_new(click) {
  if (click !== 'click') {
    var obj = document.getElementById('new');
    if (obj.innerHTML == 'New') {
      obj.innerHTML = 10;
      setTimeout(timer_new, 1000);
    } else if (obj.innerHTML == 0) {
      obj.innerHTML = 'New';
    } else {
      obj.innerHTML--;
      setTimeout(timer_new, 1000);
    }
  } else {return true;}
}


function timer_save() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('save');
  if (obj.innerHTML == 'Save') {
    obj.innerHTML = 100;
    setTimeout(timer_save, 1000);
  } else if (obj.innerHTML == 0) {
    obj.innerHTML = 'Save';
  } else {
    obj.innerHTML--;
    setTimeout(timer_save, 1000);
  }
}

function timer_deact() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('deact');
  if (obj.innerHTML == 'Deact') {
    obj.innerHTML = 85;
    setTimeout(timer_deact, 1000);
  } else if (obj.innerHTML == 0) {
    obj.innerHTML = 'Deact';
  } else {
    obj.innerHTML--;
    setTimeout(timer_deact, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
 #wrapper {
   width: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 50px;
   border: 2px green solid;
 }
 
 #counter {
   text-align: center;
   width: 216px;
   margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
   padding: 15px;
   border: 2px black solid;
 }
 
 #buttons {
   margin: 0 auto 0 86px;
 }
 
 #buttons div {
   display: inline-block;
   font-weight: 700;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin-right: 7px;
   width: 36px;
   padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
   border-radius: 3px;
   transition: 0.2s;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 #new {
   background: rgb(64, 199, 129);
   box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(53, 167, 110) inset;
 }
 
 #new:hover {
   background: rgb(53, 167, 110)
 }
 
 #new:active {
   background: rgb(33, 147, 90);
 }
 
 #save {
   background: rgb(135, 206, 250);
   box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(124, 174, 231) inset;
 }
 
 #save:hover {
   background: rgb(124, 174, 231)
 }
 
 #save:active {
   background: rgb(104, 154, 211);
 }
 
 #deact {
   background: rgb(255, 160, 122);
   box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(244, 128, 103) inset;
 }
 
 #deact:hover {
   background: rgb(244, 128, 103)
 }
 
 #deact:active {
   background: rgb(224, 108, 83);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="counter">294</div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <div id="new" onclick="start_timers();">New</div>
    <div id="save" onclick="start_timers();">Save</div>
    <div id="deact" onclick="start_timers();">Deact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Ссылка на код** - http://codepen.io/iWillCrashYou/pen/NAgWvg

Comment: это все потому, что надо останавливать таймеры перед запуском, а чтобы останавливать их надо где-то сохранить

Comment: а точно при нажатии на одну кнопку должны запускаться _все_ таймеры?

Comment: @Grundy, Можно немного подробнее. Я пробовал реализовать завершение функции с помощью параметра передаваемого функции. Если параметр передан, функция должна вернуть true, что как я  думал, должно завершить ее выполнение. И после этого повторно ее вызываю, уже без передачи параметра. Но как видно из приложенного кода, не робит. И да, таймеры должны запускаться все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вынести состояние таймеров в отдельный объект, в котором могут хранится сам таймер, название, начальное состояние.

Сохранив все это можно при каждом запуске просто вызывать [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout), который остановит запущенные таймеры.

Например так:

```js
//Нажатие на кнопки и изменение кол-ва баллов
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new').click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(+$('#counter').html() - 5);
  });

  $('#save').click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(+$('#counter').html() - 2);
  });

  $('#deact').click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(+$('#counter').html() - 1);
  });

});
var timerStates = [{
  text: 'New',
  count: 10
}, {
  text: 'Save',
  count: 100
}, {
  text: 'Deact',
  count: 85
}, ];

function start_timers() {
  timerStates.forEach(function(timerState) {
    clearTimeout(timerState.timer);
    startTimer(timerState);
  });
}

function startTimer(timerState) {
  var el = document.getElementById(timerState.text.toLowerCase());
  counterExec(timerState.count);

  function counterExec(count) {
    el.innerHTML = count || timerState.text;
    if (count)
      timerState.timer = setTimeout(counterExec, 1000, count-1);
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 2px green solid;
}
#counter {
  text-align: center;
  width: 216px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
#buttons {
  margin: 0 auto 0 86px;
}
#buttons div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 7px;
  width: 36px;
  padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#new {
  background: rgb(64, 199, 129);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(53, 167, 110) inset;
}
#new:hover {
  background: rgb(53, 167, 110)
}
#new:active {
  background: rgb(33, 147, 90);
}
#save {
  background: rgb(135, 206, 250);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(124, 174, 231) inset;
}
#save:hover {
  background: rgb(124, 174, 231)
}
#save:active {
  background: rgb(104, 154, 211);
}
#deact {
  background: rgb(255, 160, 122);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(244, 128, 103) inset;
}
#deact:hover {
  background: rgb(244, 128, 103)
}
#deact:active {
  background: rgb(224, 108, 83);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="counter">294</div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <div id="new" onclick="start_timers();">New</div>
    <div id="save" onclick="start_timers();">Save</div>
    <div id="deact" onclick="start_timers();">Deact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня были попытки сделать общий вид для функций с использованием объектов и передачи id  в getElementById, но так как с JS я очень плохо знаком, попытки были далеки от успеха. Спасибо за разъяснение, то что нужно.